# Can anybody explain what is checkpoint process?

Tags: oracle11g

When does the checkpoint occurs? Does it occurs after LGWR writes to redo log files ? And what will be the scenario when user commits transaction?

Answer (score 0):

The checkpoint is issued **after** a log switch is issued (or whenever you issue an `ALTER SYSTEM CHECKPOINT;`).
After the checkpoint the background process [CKPT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CKPT) timestamps the datafiles and control files to show that the checkpoint occurred and then it updates `v$sysstat` to show the number of checkpoint requests completed.
I guess the answer to the 3rd question would be that after the checkpoint is issued the system flushes the changed blocks from the data buffer cache into the datafiles and marks all of the datafiles with the same SCN.